# Connecting / disconnecting to bluetooth devices programmatically in Andorid apps

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an Android app which I can manage my bluetooth devices. I did some research and I found that I can discover bluetooth devices that are discoverable and I could connnect to those devies using "createBond" method.
For now, my question is how can I disconnect to the connected devices without unpairing, so that I can connect to them again after.

I've tried using the "removeBond" method to disconnect to a device, it did word, but I need to redo the pairing again before next time I want to connect to this device. I just want something like the bluetooth settings in android system settings which I can simply "disconnect" but not "forget" the device.

Comment: createBond is used to send pairing requests. And when its bonded, socket?.connect() is used to connect device and socket?.close() is used to disconnect device

Comment: After calling createBond, the device is connected. does it mean that "socket?.connect()" was automatically executed after pairing?

Answer (score 0):

CreateBond is used to send pairing requests. And when it's bonded, socket?.connect() is used to connect device, and socket?.close() is used to disconnect device.
Below is the code snippet:

```
val device = bluetoothAdapter?.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress)

// Pair with the device
try {
    device?.createBond()
    Log.d(TAG, "Pairing request sent")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error pairing with device", e)
}

// Wait for the pairing process to complete
while (device?.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
    // Do nothing while waiting for the pairing process to complete
}

// Pairing process completed successfully
Log.d(TAG, "Pairing successful")

// Connect to the device using a BluetoothSocket
val socket = device?.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)

// Connect to the device
try {
    socket?.connect()
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to device")
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to device", e)
}

// Close the socket to disconnect from the device
try {
    socket?.close()
    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from device")
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error disconnecting from device", e)
}
```